# which ObjectID should I use in node-mongodb-native

Tags: mongodb, node.js

I notice there are two ObjectID in node-mongodb-native,  which one should I use, if I save an document in native ObjectID, can I load it with pure ObjectID. Does it matter with the option of native_parser .

```
mongodb.BSONNative.ObjectID
mongodb.BSONPure.BSON.ObjectID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has changed since the last post here. Now the docs say require('mongodb').ObjectID.

Answer (score 3):

`require('mongodb/lib/mongodb/bson/bson').ObjectID`